# Why is there no cross-compiler in Arm64 version of Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

In the Amd64 version of Ubuntu, there's the `gcc-{version}-{architecture}-linux-gnu` packages that I can use to build binaries for different architectures, of which, the built binaries can be tested using `qemu-user`. But in Arm64 version of Ubuntu, there isn't such cross compiler.

Q1: Why isn't there such packages (as of 20.04 TLS)?

Next, I'd like to use the Clang/LLVM toolchain to build binaries in place of the GCC toolchain. Q2: What are the necessary library packages that I need for testing programs built for: Amd64, AArch64, PowerPC64, Sparc64? Preferablly virtual packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the main `gcc` package, the GCC cross compilers are in the `universe` repository, which means they're maintained by the community on a "best-effort" basis. The main `gcc` package is from the `main` repository, which is fully supported by Ubuntu.

The library packages needed, according to me [tracing through the dependencies of the GCC cross compiler for PowerPC64 architecture](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/focal/devel/gcc-powerpc64-linux-gnu), seems to consist of the following:

- `libgcc-${ver_of_gcc}-dev-${arch}-cross`
- `libc-dev-${arch}-cross` # this is a virtual package.

And if C++ development is desired:

- `libstdc++-dev-${arch}-cross` # this is a virtual package.

As said in the OP, the Clang/LLVM toolchain is used. The toolchain comes with the Clang C/C++/Obj-C compiler, and [a functioning linker](https://lld.llvm.org/).

---

**Additionally**

One can enable "Multiarch" and run cross compiler built for x86_64 on arm64 through user-space QEMU program. Relevant article: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO